# What is the best practice with the borrow checker for inspecting mutable references?

Tags: rust, immutability, borrow-checker

I want to take a linked list and populate it with instances of a struct, but only if the list doesn't already contain the item I'm considering adding.

I'm working with points so if (3,5) is in the list I don't want to add it, otherwise I do.

My current code:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

struct Location {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut locations = LinkedList::new();

    loop {
        let location_set = &mut locations;
        // Scanner stuff happens.
        if !has_location(location_set, &next_checkpoint_x, &next_checkpoint_y) {
            let point = Location {
                x: next_checkpoint_x,
                y: next_checkpoint_y,
            };
            locations.push_back(point);
        }
    }
}

fn has_location(location_list: LinkedList<Location>, target_x: &i32, target_y: &i32) -> bool {
    true // Just until I can figure out this mutability stuff
}
```

I've been able to get it to run by these changes, but this seems wrong to me.

```
loop {
    if !has_location(&mut locations, &next_checkpoint_x, &next_checkpoint_y) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

```
fn has_location(location_list: &LinkedList<Location>, target_x: &i32, target_y: &i32) -> bool {
    true
}
```

I don't want `has_location` to be able to mutate the linked list, I just want it to be able to borrow it so that it can look inside of it.  I don't want to have to think about `has_location` (or a similar function) affecting the linked lists it inspects.  This is why I created the `location_set`.  I want something to refer to locations in a read-only sense and that to be passed to the `has_location` function and for what is being referred to (locations) to not be destroyed after calling the `has_location` function.  I include the `&` in the passing of the parameters in the call of the function, because I don't want the parameters passed destroyed - so I want them borrowed?

Is what I'm wanting something that makes sense - if I originally declare locations as a mutable linked list can I pass an immutable version of it to a function to evaluate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a mutable borrow, you can always *reborrow* it as an immutable borrow. This even happens implicitly (a `&mut T` will coerce to `&T`). Therefore, you can just pass `location_set` to `has_location` directly. Or if you want to make it clear that the function doesn't mutate its argument, you can write `&*location_set` instead of `location_set` (though I find this to be unnecessary).

Also, note that you can't use the mutable borrow while the immutable borrow exists; the immutable borrow freezes the data structure while it's in scope. Likewise, you can't use a variable while there's a mutable borrow on that variable in scope. In your first code sample, you can't refer to `locations` while `location_set` is in scope, because `location_set` takes a mutable borrow on `locations`, but you can just use `location_set` again, because `push_back` only requires a mutable borrow (it doesn't take a `LinkedList` by value).

A function that merely inspects a data structure will usually receive an immutable borrow to the data structure. If the data structure was passed by value instead, the function would take ownership of it and would therefore destroy it before returning (unless it's moved elsewhere). Therefore, yes, you want `has_location` to accept an immutable borrow to the `LinkedList`. By accepting an immutable borrow (as opposed to a mutable borrow), the compiler will prevent you from modifying the `LinkedList` (unless you use unsafe code).

Putting it all together:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

struct Location {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut locations = LinkedList::new();
    let next_checkpoint_x = 0;
    let next_checkpoint_y = 0;

    loop {
        let location_set = &mut locations;
        // Scanner stuff happens.
        if !has_location(location_set, &next_checkpoint_x, &next_checkpoint_y) {
            let point = Location { x: next_checkpoint_x, y: next_checkpoint_y };
            location_set.push_back(point);
        }
    }
}

fn has_location(location_list: &LinkedList<Location>, target_x: &i32, target_y: &i32) -> bool {
    true
}
```

---

> Something I don't understand though is in your example, `location_set` is passed to `has_location` directly (so the function owns it, right?). This in my mind means that at the end of `has_location`'s scope, `location_set` should be destroyed, no? How does `location_set` continue to exist to be used in the `if` block?

No, `has_location` doesn't own `location_set`. If this was any other type that doesn't implement `Copy` (e.g. `String`), then you would be right, but references have special rules to make them more convenient to use.

When you pass a reference to a function, the compiler will automatically *reborrow* that reference to produce a new reference, generally with a shorter lifetime. Here, the compiler is reborrowing the mutable reference and producing an immutable reference; the mutable reference cannot be used until the immutable reference goes out of scope (the immutable reference is not bound to a variable here, so you don't really notice that). Conceptually, it's as if you were passing an immutable reference to the mutable reference (in Rust, a `& &mut T` doesn't let you mutate the `T`, because there could be multiple copies of that outer reference), it's just that the two references are "flattened".

> Also if `location_set` is immutable, how is `push_back` able to add to the end of the list, is it because the function coerces the mutable borrow into an immutable borrow?

`location_set` is still a mutable reference (because we create it with the `&mut` operator). The fact that `has_location` operates on an immutable reference doesn't change the fact that `location_set` is a mutable reference. Once the call to `has_location` has been evaluated, `location_set` can be reused as a mutable reference, so mutation operations such as `push_back` are allowed.

Remember that mutability is Rust is purely a compile-time concept; the `mut` or lack of `mut` simply lets the compiler validate that your code doesn't do illegal operations, but once your code is compiled, these markers are nowhere to be seen.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you.  Something I don't understand though is in your example, location_set is passed to has_location directly (so the function owns it, right?).  This in my mind means that at the end of has_location's scope, location_set should be destroyed, no?  How does location_set continue to exist to be used in the if block?  Also if location_set is immutable, how is push_back able to add to the end of the list, is it because the function coerces the mutable borrow into an immutable borrow?    Thanks!

Comment: See my reply at the end of the answer.